# Undefined index: user_phone

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I know that there is other similar questions but the error is caused by different reasons with different solution.

I have a Wordpress registration form template file that work perfect with this line, the phone number is captured and send to client profile/DB :

```
<input type="text" name="user_phone" id="user_phone" class="input" placeholder="<?php _e('Telefon', ET_DOMAIN);?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( stripslashes( $user_phone ) ); ?>" tabindex="25"></div>
```

I have tried to use the same line on social registration form in order for the client to share the phone number but the phone number its saved on DB/client profile. This is the error on debug file:

```
Undefined index: user_phone in /home/admin/public_html/mysite.net/wp-content/plugins/sms-verification/sms-verification.php on line 333
```

sms-verification.php is a plugin file,

This is line 333 from debug error :

```
 $phone = $_POST['user_phone'];
```

Function context of above line:

```
function user_register( $user_id ) {
    $enabled = wedevs_sms_get_option( 'register_form' );
    $phone = $_POST['user_phone'];

    if ( $enabled == 'on' ) {
        $gateway_obj = WeDevs_SMS_Gateways::instance();
        $status = $gateway_obj->send( $phone );

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'sms_registered', 'yes' );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wedevssms_mobile', $phone );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'sms_verified', 0 );

        //if sms sent successfully, update the code
        //else, insert a random code to the profile
        if ( $status['success'] == true ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wedevssms_referenceno', $status['code'] );
        } else {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wedevssms_referenceno', rand( 1000, 9999 ) );
        }
    }
}
```

social registration form:

```
 <form id="form_username" method="post" action="">
            <div class="fre-input-field">
                <input type="hidden" name="et_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'authentication' ) ?>">
            <input type="text" name="user_phone" id="user_phone" class="input" placeholder="<?php _e('Telefon', ET_DOMAIN);?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( stripslashes( $user_phone ) ); ?>" tabindex="25">  
                <input type="hidden" name="user_email" value="<?php if ( isset( $auth['user_email'] ) ) {
                    echo $auth['user_email'];
                } ?>">
                <input type="text" name="user_login"
                       value="<?php echo isset( $auth['user_login'] ) ? $auth['user_login'] : "" ?>"
                       placeholder="<?php _e( 'Username', ET_DOMAIN ) ?>">
            </div>
            <?php
            $role_default      = ae_get_social_login_user_roles_default();
            $social_user_roles = ae_get_option( 'social_user_role', false );
            if ( ! $social_user_roles ) {
                $social_user_roles = ae_get_social_login_user_roles_default();
            }
            if ( $social_user_roles && count( $social_user_roles ) >= 1 ) { ?>
                <div class="fre-input-field">
                    <select name="user_role" id="user_role" class="fre-chosen-single">
                        <option selected disabled value=""><?php _e('Choose your role',ET_DOMAIN);?></option>
                        <?php foreach ( $social_user_roles as $key => $value ) { ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $role_default[ $value ]; ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="fre-input-field">
                <input type="submit" class="fre-submit-btn btn-submit" value="<?php _e( 'Sign Up', ET_DOMAIN ); ?>">
            </div>
        </form>
```

How to fix it my code in order to work  ?

Comment: `user_phone` does not exist in your `$_POST`. This can be caused by not having a form element with `name="user_phone"`, if it is assigned then it could have been disabled before submission, if it's not disabled then make sure your form is using `method="POST"`, if you are using `method="POST"` then make sure the form element is actually inside the `<form>` tag, or you are totally confusing which file is producing the HTML form and which file is processing it.

Comment: Its using method="POST", I have updated the question with full social register form.

Comment: I have checked the website form and its showing the proper input with correct name and id user_phone. I have added the line you said on function user_register() , when submit the form I get error on page 'Undefined' but the submission goes and saves the data on DB without the phone number of course..